# Dating photo of family members in front of house in Texas?

Tags: 20th-century, photo-identification, photo-dating, texas

I've got a family photo:

[image]

I believe the boy, second from left, is either born in 1901 or 1930, so given the boy looks to be around 12, that would make photo taken around 1912 or 1942.

Can we tell from their clothes or the house, the likely date of this photo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The skirt length alone rules out 1912.  It is consistent with 1942.  As are the other clothes.  Remember that people usually did not wear the latest fashions, especially away from large cities and if they were not wealthy.  They often wore the same well-kept clothes for many years, updating as needed.